# Find The Coordinates of Atoms

Tags: trigonometry, vectors, coordinate-systems

I have this problem that I have not been able to solve for a very long time.

I have 4 atoms in 2D space (XY). I know the coordinates of the blue atoms and the distances between all atoms (blue and red).

How can I find the coordinates of the red atoms?

[image]

Comment: You can't. The system has one degree of freedom.

Comment: You can however find a surface on which the atoms will lie. Also if you reduce it to 2D you can find the coordinates of red atoms.

Comment: ok how can i find the atoms in 2D space? if i understand the method i might understand how to expand it to 3D space.

Comment: Each distance gives you a circle on which a red atom must lie, so you’re going to be computing intersections of pairs of circles, which in general will give you two points for each pair of circles. Without additional information, the best that you can do is compute the $2\times2=4$ possible configurations of the red atoms. In 3D, you are intersecting spheres instead, which in general will give you a circle of possible positions for each atom.

Answer (score 1):

Polar coordinates will be very useful here.

To find the location of the carbon atom, imagine that the origin of a polar coordinate system is at the left-most of the two calcium atoms. In that case, the carbon atom is at the point $(r_C,\theta_C)=(2.4,0.222)$ in that polar coordinate system (angle converted to radians). This means that in a rectangular coordinate system centered on the left calcium atom, the carbon atom's coordinates are given by

\begin{align}
x_C&=r_C\cos\theta_C=2.4\cos(0.222)=2.34 \\
y_C&=r_C\sin\theta_C=2.4\sin(0.222)=0.53
\end{align}

Switching back to the coordinate system shown in the picture, we now know that the carbon atom is $2.34$ units to the right of the left calcium atom and $0.53$ units above it. We can add those relative coordinates to the coordinates of the left calcium atom as shown in the picture to find that the carbon atom is located at the point $(1.0+2.34,2.0+0.53)=(3.34,2.53)$.

---

We can use the exact same trick to find the coordinates of the nitrogen atom. In a polar coordinate system centered on the left calcium atom, the nitrogen atom is at the point $(r_N,\theta_N)=(1.5,-0.262)$ (angle converted to radians again; also, this angle happens to be exactly $-\frac{\pi}{12}$, but the decimal approximation is perfectly fine). Therefore, the nitrogen atom's coordinates in a rectangular coordinate system centered on the left calcium atom are:

\begin{align}
x_N&=r_N\cos\theta_N=1.45 \\
y_N&=r_N\sin\theta_N=-0.39
\end{align}

Switching back to the coordinate system shown in the picture again, we can add the relative coordinates of the nitrogen atom to the displayed coordinates of the left calcium atom to find that the nitrogen atom is located at the point $(1.0+1.45,2.0-0.39)=(2.45,1.61)$.

As a quick sanity check, performing the same kinds of calculations relative to the right-most calcium atom yields very similar coordinates for the carbon and nitrogen atoms, so we can be confident that the above results are reasonably correct.